# Why doesn't the Map prototype have a `.map()` function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I see a lots posts asking about how to map(Array.prototype.map) a Map.  Most of the solutions is do the `Array.from(...)` but what I want to know is why doesn't Map itself support `.map()`?

Maybe some performance issue or we don't have this kind use case?

https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
Maybe is definition of map is 
`The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.` but for this we can have different definition for `Map.prototype.map`

Comment: This probably has to do with how there is no `.map()` for Objects either.  `map()` is for an array, and returns an array so its behavior for objects or Maps seems like it would have to be different.  However, there's no `.map()` for `Set` either.

Comment: Additionally, you would expect all iterators to have a map function as well... But maybe at some point [transducers](https://medium.com/@roman01la/understanding-transducers-in-javascript-3500d3bd9624) will become a first class thing?

Comment: There are actually some active discussions that approach this idea of having such methods on all/any iterable. For instance https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers/issues/8 and https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers/issues/5 So it may come, one day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Map` is built in similar concept to the `Object` but not an `Array`.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys.

So, you can notice that `Object` has no property order while `Map` has.

Did you notice, the `Map` has key value pair like:

```
[[ 1, 'one' ],[ 2, 'two' ]]
```

There are differences on [Map vs Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared) you can look on the doc.

You can see this example to know why this is compared with `Object`:

```
const map = new Map([[3, 'three'], [2, 'two'], [2, 'four']]);
console.log(map); // returns {3 => "three", 2 => "four"}
```

You found it that it's not like an array. But like an object. So, you can try what you try with `Object`. You cannot use the `.map()` directly with `Object` but you you'll need to use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)...

Like this you'll need to use `Map` with:

[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
let iterable = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]);

for (let entry of iterable) {
  console.log(entry);
}
// [a, 1]
// [b, 2]
// [c, 3]

for (let [key, value] of iterable) {
  console.log(value);
}
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
const mapMap = function(map, mapFunction){

  const toReturn = [];
  map.forEach(function(value, key){ // be careful to the args order
    toReturn.push(mapFunction(value, key));
  })

  return toReturn;
}
```

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
Array.from(p).map( ([key, value]) => value * value )
```

The examples are extracted from the following sources on which you may be interested to look in further:

[Array vs Set vs Map](https://codeburst.io/array-vs-set-vs-map-vs-object-real-time-use-cases-in-javascript-es6-47ee3295329b)

[How to map a map](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-map-a-map-12c6ef1c5b2e)

[ES6 Map vs Object: What and When](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/es6-map-vs-object-what-and-when-b80621932373)

Comment: `Map.prototype.entries()` returns a map iterator, not an array. I got burned by that recently.

Comment: "So, you can notice that Object has no property order" I can't notice that, and actually it does have property order. All access methods won't preserve it though, but nonetheless, it has.

Comment: Both Array and Map prototypes implement iteration protocol, while Object is not.

.map method walks through iterable object and create a new object of same size containing transformed values in the same order.

But, suddenly, Map does not have such method.

The original question is not answered. (BTW, Array is an object, too.)